# Stumped on JS Epoch Convertion

Tags: javascript

In epoch
**1265997351408**
is
**Fri Feb 12 2010 12:55:51 GMT-0500 (EST)**

I am trying to write it as:
**February, 12 2010**

But I am getting: **November, 10 42087**

What am I doing wrong?

```
function makeHumanDate(epoch) {
   var theDate = epoch * 1000
   var months = new Array(13);
   months[0]  = "January";
   months[1]  = "February";
   months[2]  = "March";
   months[3]  = "April";
   months[4]  = "May";
   months[5]  = "June";
   months[6]  = "July";
   months[7]  = "August";
   months[8]  = "September";
   months[9]  = "October";
   months[10] = "November";
   months[11] = "December";
   var d           = new Date(theDate);
   var monthnumber = d.getUTCMonth();
   var monthname   = months[monthnumber];
   var monthday    = d.getUTCDate();
   var year        = d.getFullYear();
   if(year < 2000) { year = year + 1900; }
   var dateString = monthname +
                    ', ' +
                    monthday +
                    ' ' +
                    year;
   // Goal is: February, 12 2010
   return dateString;
}
```

I know its something dumb but I've been stuck for a while.  Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: Just some unsolicited advice. You can define your months array like this `var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to multiply `epoch` by 1000 in your example code - if you take this out, it works as expected :)

A little code clean-up

```
function makeHumanDate(epoch) {
   var months = ["January",
                 "February",
                 "March",
                 "April",
                 "May",
                 "June",
                 "July",
                 "August",
                 "September",
                 "October",
                 "November",
                 "December"],
       d = new Date(epoch),
       month = months[d.getUTCMonth()],
       day = d.getUTCDate(),
       year = d.getFullYear();

   // not needed as getFullYear returns the full year in 4 digits
   //if( year < 2000 ) year += 1900; 

   return month + ', ' + day + ' ' + year;
}
```

Comment: Only thing I had to change for this to work was Date(epoch/1). Thanks for getting me unstuck.

Comment: if you need to make that change to `epoch`, is it a string then? you could either parse it to an int before passing in or use the unary operator `+` on `epoch` here - `new Date(+epoch)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but your input is broken. If I use http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm
I get the same result you do.

Your timestamp seems to need a division by 1000 to get it back into a reasonable frame, after which I get the correct result.